# Digits won't work with indian numbers starting from 91

Tags: android, twitter-digits

I'm using digits in my android app for mobile verification. But it won't accept numbers starting from 91 (e.g 9177665544) saying 'Unable to send an SMS for this mobile number.'. I think something is messy with indian country code +91 and initial digits of mobile number 91 . Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

```
Digits.authenticate(
    digitsCallback,
    R.style.CustomDigitsTheme,
    "+91"+et_phone.getText().toString().trim(),
    Boolean.parseBoolean(null)
);
```